# How to install Windows 7 on laptop with Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, laptop, bios

How to install Windows 7 on laptop with Ubuntu preinstalled? (I want replace Ubuntu, as I already have Ubuntu on another PC). I have Windows installation ISO on DVD. Should I first remove Ubuntu via reformatting drive? The HDD is 500GB: will be fine to set 100GB partition for Windows and programs?

Comment: What step are you stuck at exactly, there are lots of tutorials, on dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows

Comment: Install windows over the top in the you will be ask if you wish to write over

Comment: @sonex In the Install process it will detect the current OS on the hard drive and ask if you wish to save it or Install windows over the top - 'Install windows over the top' you can change the size of the partition after installing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace Ubuntu, just fire up the Win7 installer.
It gives you the option to format the drive and set the size of the partition.
Just click on expert install when the question comes up and delete all the old partitions.
100GB is fine for a bare windows install and a normal count of standard programs. If you dont play big sized games, store personal data of exordinary size or install many programs like the adobe creative suite it should work like a charm.

Comment: Not fully clear, should I select "Quick" format or "Full" format? Also, should I format the whole drive? Some manuals says that first should be repaired boot sector (as originally there is Ubuntu installed): does this required?

Comment: Quick format should be perfectly fine, full should be tried if the first one doesnt show the wanted results. The boot sector will be built by Windows. So, if you want to fully replace Ubuntu, formating the whole drive will do the job. But dont forget to backup your personal files as they will all be gone.